# Cannot run Box2D testbed

Tags: visual-studio-2017, box2d

I downloaded Box2D from their official GitHub page and am using VS2017. I retargeted the solution to Windows 10 (10.0.16299.0), then reconfigured the project's properties to set the Windows SDK version to 10.0.16299.0.

I built the solution and it worked, but when I tried to run the "testbed" project it gave me an error saying this in the console:

> Assertion failed: 0, file
>   c:\frameworks\box2d\box2d-master\box2d\imgui\imgui_draw.cpp, line 1171

and this in the main window:

> Debug error! abort() has been called

Answer (score 2):

**Analysis:**

Looking at the source code for the assertion on [line 1171 in the `imgui_draw.cpp` file](https://github.com/erincatto/Box2D/blob/master/Box2D/imgui/imgui_draw.cpp#L1171), it appears this would get triggered if the font file that is being looked for can't be loaded. It seems a safe bet that the Testbed application is looking for the `Data/DroidSans.ttf` file. That's because that's the only context the testbed appears to call the function which is asserting. The `Data/DroidSans.ttf` file's full project-relative path is `Box2D/Box2D/Testbed/Data/DroidSans.ttf`.

**To solve this problem:**

Either:

1. Set the working directory so that the font file is found at
   `Data/DroidSans.ttf` relative to it ([Building.txt](https://github.com/erincatto/Box2D/blob/master/Box2D/Building.txt) says to set the working directory to `..\..\Testbed`), or
2. Copy the `DroidSans.ttf`
   file so that its folder location, relative to where you are running
   the Testbed from, is `Data/DroidSans.ttf`.

Alternatively, it may be
    that building Box2D via `premake` (as intended) avoids this problem
    altogether.

**Background:**

Incidentally, I've seen other users run across this font file not being in the location necessary and there's at least [one issue](https://github.com/erincatto/Box2D/issues/417) that's been filed (and closed) about this.

Comment: @AncWar if this solves the problem, please accept my answer and up vote it. If it doesn't solve the problem, please add to this comment section further details. Thanks!